# What is the difference between [Required] and [Required()] in c#

Tags: c#, attributes

I read some documents from github and found there was a difference while creating the object

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

What is the difference between them? Thanks for help

Comment: What difference did you find?

Comment: Nothing. You put a constructor expression between square brackets for an attribute on C#, but the parentheses are optional. You could also use `[RequiredAttribute]` or `[RequiredAttribute()]`. I personally like it without the parens (unless you are using constructor parameters or property setters and need them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is different between [Required] and [Required()] in c#

Nothing.

Attributes are classes which can be configured by a *constructor*. If there is a *default constructor*, you can either use the attribute with parenthesis or not, it's up to you.

```
[Required]
[Required()]
```

If it has a constructor you could use:

```
[SomeOtherAttribute("bob")]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no functional differences in your examples. The parentheses are optional for attributes where you are not passing any constructor arguments.